# How do I find a specific child element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

I've just started using javascript and am trying to do the following:
My html doc contains divs and span elements like below.
I want to create a variable which will store the value of `my-new-id` for a specific div child element.
The only information I have to go on, is that I always know what the span `text` will be cause it's based on a username. 
Therefore, how would I get the value of `my-new-id` for `user1`?

I have already figured out how to navigate to the correct div elemenet using the document.getElementById method. I then try to use a jquery selector such as `:contains`, but get stuck.

Many thanks on advance.

```
<div id=1>
<span my-new-id=x>user1</span>
<span my-new-id=y>user2</span>
<span my-new-id=z>user3</span>
</div>

<div id=2>
<span my-new-id=x>user10</span>
<span my-new-id=y>user1</span>
<span my-new-id=z>user30</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using the jQuery library? Else the jquery-selectors tag is inappropriate. You could use `querySelectorAll` to get the spans directly.

Comment: @Christoph It would appear so, since he describes using `:contains` in the question.

Comment: @Asad well, then there would be no need for a native dom-method, right?

Comment: @Christoph Right, you'd just use `$`. You could still use native methods if you felt like it though.

Comment: @Christoph, yes, we are using the jQuery library.

Comment: Then you should not use `document.getElementById` but the jquery Selector `$` to select the elements to have full access to all jQuery Methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
var val = $('span:contains("user1")').attr('my-new-id');
```

A couple of additional points:

- Do not use IDs that begin with a number. This is not allowed in the HTML4 spec, and can cause unexpected behavior in some browsers. Instead, prefix your ID's with an alphabetic string, like this:

  ```
  <div id="container1">
      ...
  </div>
  ```
- I would recommend that you use `data-*` attributes instead of making up non existent attributes. You can make `data` attributes like this:

  ```
  <span data-new-id="x">user1</span>
  ```

  You can then retrieve this value using:

  ```
  $('span:contains("user1")').data('newId');
  ```

  Note that the attribute name has been stripped of dashes and camel-cased.

Comment: Cool. So this gets me the value of the attribute I am after.

I already have a variable like below which stores the correct div, how do I then prefix this variable to your example, so that I can search for the attribute?

var myDiv = document.getElementById('DivNumber2');

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Eddie You can include it in the selector expression, as in: `$('DivNumber2 span:contains("user1")').attr('my-new-id');`

Comment: @Eddie as I mentioned in the comment to your question, you cannot use jQuery Methods like Asad does on a plain DOM-Object you get from `getElementById`. You would need to use something like `myDiv.attributes["my-new-id"]`.

Comment: I tried the following but when i debug I get a value of 'undefined' for my new variable $myNewVariable.

Taking your advice i'm now trying to do something like this:
I have a div called user-name2. 
A value in a span under that div called david. 
And an attribute on the span called 'my-user-id'.  

Maybe my syntax is incorrect? This is my line of javascript. 

$myNewVariable = $('user-name2 span:contains("david")').attr('my-user-id');

Comment: @Eddie Yes, I made a slight mistake. When specifying an ID in a selector, you need to precede it with `#`. So your statement should be: `$myNewVariable = $('#user-name2 span:contains("david")').attr('my-user-id');`

Comment: @Asad, 
That's awesome! I think i have 1 final bit then i'm done.

If I want to replace user-name2, with a variable I have already defined, do I need to remove the hash and quotes? e.g. I want to replace it with a variable I have called $thisUserName

$myNewVariable = $('#user-name2 span:contains("david")').attr('my-user-id');

Comment: @Eddie `$myNewVariable = $('#' + $thisUserName + ' span:contains("david")').attr('my-user-id');`